# ContourPlot3D not wotking for slicing z axis in the ranges of 10^-13

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I am using ContourPlot3D to obtain a slice plane at z = constant. However I find that the plane's position is not moving when the range is of the order of 10^-13. I am using the following code.

```
zSlice = ContourPlot3D[z == -6*10^-13, {x, 0, 3*10^-6}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -8*10^-13,2*10^-13}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green],Mesh -> None,ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {-8*10^-13, 2*10^-13}]
zSlice = ContourPlot3D[z == -4*10^-13, {x, 0, 3*10^-6}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -8*10^-13,2*10^-13}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green],Mesh -> None,ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {-8*10^-13, 2*10^-13}]
```

The above code doesn't change the z=constant plane in the plot. What could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a *bad* idea to work with really small or really large parameters in expressions that you then use in plots or equations. Instead you should *re-scale* your quantities into an *appropriate system of units*. For example, in atomic systems you should use [atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units). The wikipedia entry on [nondimensionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) is a good introduction.

Also, I see that you have manually typed in `epsilon = 8.85*10^-12`, which I assume is the permittivity of free space. Note that Mathematica has built-in access to the current value of [physical constants](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PhysicsAndChemistryDataAndComputation.html). And this quantity now has an *exact* value:

```
WolframAlphaResult["permittivity of free space", {{"Definition", 1}, "Content"},
   PodStates -> {"Value__Show exact value"}]
```

I'd bet that if you re-scale your parameters, all the problems you are experiencing will disappear and also your plots will look more elegant as the ticks will be numbers of order 1.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I re-scaled my values and hence I am able to get the planes cutting the axis and also able to move this plane with good precision.  Thanks for your input on physical constants.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid  possible precision issues, you can rescale the contour levels and vertical plot range to run from -8 to 2 (say) and use custom ticks for the vertical axis to show the scaled-back tick labels:

```
ContourPlot3D[{z == -6, z == -4}, {x, 0, 3*10^-6}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -8,
   2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green],  Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red]},
  Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  PlotRange -> {-8, 2}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{-8, 2}, (10^-13) {-8, 2}][-8, 2]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** to combine with another `Plot3D` output you can rescale the first argument of `Plot3D` and use `zSlice4` first in `Show` (so that the option values of `zlice3D` for ticks is in effect in `Show`):

```
fig1 = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2] 10^12, {x, -5*10^-12, 2*10^-12}, {y, 0, 2*10^-12}];
zSlice4 = ContourPlot3D[{z == -3, z == -2}, {x, -5*10^-12, 2*10^-12}, 
   {y, 0, 2*10^-12}, {z, -5, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green], Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red]}, 
  Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 2}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{-5, 2}, (10^-12) {-5, 2}][-5, 2]}];

Show[zSlice4, fig1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I need to add this to another Plot3D using Show[] command. But I am facing an error there. Please see the code snippet below: fig1 = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -5*10^-12, 2*10^-12}, {y, 0, 2*10^-12},ImageSize -> Large] zSlice4 = ContourPlot3D[{z == -3}, {x, -5*10^-12, 2*10^-12}, {y, 0,2*10^-12}, {z, -5, 2},ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green], Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red]}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large,PlotRange -> {-5, 2},Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic,Charting`FindTicks[{-5, 2}, (10^-12) {-5, 2}][-5, 2]}] Show[fig1, zSlice4] Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. But I still face a problem in the output plot I am getting using this ticks. The output x axis is protruding beyond the specified limit. k = 0.439; epsilon = 8.85*10^-12; A = 960*10^-12; g = 3*10^-6; m = 
 4.4736*10^-12; V = 13;

Comment: @Raghuram, i suggest you update your  question with that example showing  what roles `k`, `epsilon`, `A`,`g` and `V` play in `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot3D`.

Comment: Yes I have updated the question. Sorry for missing the complete code snippet.

Comment: @Raghuram, you updated your deleted answer; you should put that information in the question, not in a deleted answer.

Comment: I have updated the question now. Very sorry for so much confusion in updation as I am a beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

My Plot3D now is a **surface** rather than a plane. When I did as you mentioned, I am able to see only the top surface of my plot and not the entire surface. So I changed my Plot3D also with ticks command. But I am now facing an error that my output plot is protruding beyond the x range specified. Pls see the code snippet below.

```
k = 0.439; epsilon = 8.85*10^-12; A = 960*10^-12; g = 3*10^-6; m = 4.4736*10^-12; V = 13;
MyOut[x_, xdot_] := 0.5*m*xdot^2   + 0.5*k*x^2 - (0.5*epsilon*A*V^2)/(g - x);
fig1 = Plot3D[MyOut[x, xdot]*10^12, {x, 0, g}, {xdot, -2, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x,xdot,MyOutput}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 2}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Charting`FindTicks[{-5, 2}, (10^-12) {-5, 2}][-5, 2]}];
zSlice4 = 
 ContourPlot3D[{z == -1}, {x, 0, g}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -5, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Green], 
    Opacity[0.5, Lighter@Red]}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> {-5, 2}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Charting`FindTicks[{-5, 2}, (10^-12) {-5, 2}][-5, 2]}];
Show[zSlice4, fig1]
```

Comment: scaling factor 10^-12 was for the specific case `fig1 = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -5*10^-12, 2*10^-12}, {y, 0, 2*10^-12},ImageSize -> Large] ` in your comment. For the new function `MyOut` you need to find the scaling factor based on the range of `xdot` and `x`

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.